# How to fix error - Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am facing this error, while creating a login form in the word subscribe under the submit function in the code below. The error says  Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'. How can I go about fixing this issue?
The code is as shown:

login component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
loginForm!: FormGroup;
isSubmitted=false;
results: any = false;
  constructor(private formbuilder:FormBuilder, private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.formbuilder.group({
      // email:['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      name: ['',Validators.required],
      password: ['',Validators.required]
    });
    //loginForm.controls.email
    //use getter property instead
    //fc.email
  }
get fc(){
  return this.loginForm.controls;
}
submit(){
  this.isSubmitted = true;
  if(this.loginForm.valid)
  
  this.authService.authUser(this.loginForm.value.name, 
    this.loginForm.value.password).subscribe(data => { 
      //error lies in line above(underlined subscribe)
    this.results = data;
    if (this.results[0].auth) 
    {
    this.authService.setSecureToken(this.loginForm.value.name);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/user');
    } else{
     console.log("Wrong username or password")
     }
    });
     }
     }
```

AuthUser function:

```
 authUser(username: string, pw: string) {
    return this.http.post<any[]>(this.authuser, {
      'username': username,
      'password': pw
    }),
    console.log('user registered!')
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should show the code of `authUser()` in `authService` but it looks like it returns `void` instead of an Observable. Fix the code in `authUser()` in order to return an observable. I guess you are doing a HTTP call, therefore you don't need the `subscribe()` inside `authUser`

------ EDIT ------

you are passing `authUser` to `authUser`, I don't think you intend to make a recursive call here.
You should put the url of the Backend there (a string)

```js
 authUser(username: string, pw: string):Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(YOUR_URL_HERE, {
      'username': username,
      'password': pw
    });
    console.log('user registered!'); // This will never be called because it's after the "return"
  }
```

Comment: I have added in the code for authUser above :)

Answer (score 1):

You are returning void instead of Observable as @Zerotwelve mentioned.

You can check the data type return by `authUser()` by `typeof(authUser())`.

In order to return an observable, you cannot call subscribe in `authUser()` function. If you do need to do something, you can use rxjs `pipe` and `map`.

For example:

```
authUser(usernameEmail: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
  this.http.post<any>('auth', { usernameEmail, password }).pipe(
    map((res) => {
      this.usernameMessage = res.message;
      return res.valid;
    })
  )
}
```